# Setting SSL vs using a DLL for authentication login

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, ssl, active-directory

Currently, we have the following situation:

1st, there is a web application and when a user need to login the web application, the user will provide his/her account username and password.

The username and password will be authenticated with the AD using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace Access
{
  public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, txtboxDomain.Text))
        {
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(txtboxUsername.Text, txtboxPassword.Text);
            if (isValid == true)
            {
                lblLogin.Text = "VALID";
                Session["Person"] = txtboxUsername.Text;
                Session.Timeout = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                lblLogin.Text = "INVALID";
            }
        }
    }


  }
}
```

However, a colleague 'A' mention that the above way is not safe at all.

The reason she provide is as follows:

- There is no SSL setup at the IIS.
- Even if there is no SSL Setup at the IIS, at least use the IT Department's security DLL files to provide the authentication method.

However, another colleague 'B' doubt her answer and he give that since the code will be authenticated against a Active Directory (AD), surely it will be secure and therefore there is no need to setup a SSL at the IIS where the web application is hosted.

Also, he told her that the IT Department's security DLL files might not provide the additional secure since firstly, it is closed-box and secondly, he believe that it only reduce the need to code for the authentication method.

So, may I know at what extent is my colleague A is correct or my colleague B is correct?

Comment: SSL provides transport security which was absolutely nothing to do with the AD query.

Comment: But user name and password is transmitted as clear text within lan and could easily be achieved using network sniffer.

Comment: So, does it mean that both of my colleague is actually wrong? (or maybe they are partially correct?)

Comment: Maybe your colleague A was afraid of the fact that you may be sending the user credentials unencrypted over the wire. That's why A proposed to use SSL. I would also recommend you to use SSL.

Comment: Why do you waste your time and do not configure IIS to perform Windows auth (SPNEGO)?

Answer (score 0):

For this to prove Wireshark is the only tool you need.

Simply configure a filter to capture the packets being sent on port 443 to your web server and then drill down through them.

Post the form without HTTPS first (port 80), then afterwards compare the two.

Comment: In your case you don't have ssl, so simply post the form on port 80 and check the results in wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way would be to use integrated Windows Authentication, so the user doesn't even have to type in the password.

In the code above without SSL, the password will be sent cleartext from the client's browser to the webserver.  It is possible to send cleartext username and password to Active Directory.  You'll have to check the .NET docs if your configuration above encrypts the connection from the webserver to the LDAP server (or just use a packet sniffer like Wireshark) for pc.ValidateCredentials.